# What is location of getLocationOnScreen return for?

Tags: android

As i understand that when we pass int[2] location array into view.getLocationOnScreen(location), we will get left,top coordinates of that view. But when i debug this function, i see that location return for right,top coordinates of that view. my screen is 480x800, i margin right for view is 40, so the right coordinate of view is 440 , it equal to location[0] return from view.getLocationOnScreen(location). Why location[0] return for right coordinate of view?

Comment: Looking at the docs, it doesn't even say which corner (or any corner) the "location" is supposed to be.  It would make sense for it to be the left, but it doesn't seem like it's REQUIRED for it to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is exact return for left,top coordinates of that view. I get wrong value because my view still not rendered before i call view.getLocationOnScreen(location).

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the accepted answer, the coordinate does appear to be the **top-left** corner of the view as per the implementation of `getLocationOnScreen`; also, the y-axis is inverted.

```
public void getLocationOnScreen(@Size(2) int[] outLocation) {
    getLocationInWindow(outLocation);

    final AttachInfo info = mAttachInfo;
    if (info != null) {
        outLocation[0] += info.mWindowLeft;
        outLocation[1] += info.mWindowTop;
    }
}
```